# Replace all occurrences of a character in a line, after match

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I have various lines like this:

```
   12 0.185861000 4294967296 STATE A variable name
   12 0.187326000 4294967296 STATE Another variable name
   12 0.187629000 4294967296 STATE Another variable name
   12 0.187823000 4294967296 STATE A variable name
```

Which I need to transform into

```
   12 0.185861000 4294967296 STATE A_variable_name
   12 0.187326000 4294967296 STATE Another_variable_name
   12 0.187629000 4294967296 STATE Another_variable_name
   12 0.187823000 4294967296 STATE A_variable_name
```

However, "A variable name" appears in lines not containing "STATE", and the whitespaces should not be removed there. And obviously there are whitespaces before "A variable name" in lines containing "STATE", which shouldn't be removed either.

So I need to replace all white spaces in all lines after "STATE". I thought of something like:

```
perl -pi -e "s/\h/_/g if /^.+STATE\h/" $1
```

But that replaces the whitespaces before "STATE". And of course something like

```
perl -pi -e "s/^(.+STATE\h)(.*)\h/\1\2_/g" $1
```

Replaces only the first white space after "STATE ". Any hints? I couldn't find anything, probably because the search queries for something like this are kind of vague.

Comment: That `$1` file name looks a bit suspicious. Is this inline code somewhere other than the shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with sed:

```
sed ':a;s/\(STATE [^ ]*\) /\1_/;ta;' file
```

details:

```
:a                       # define a label "a"
s/\(STATE [^ ]*\) /\1_/  # replace the first space after "STATE "
ta                       # go to label "a" if something is replaced
```

One way with perl: (that uses the `\G` anchor to ensure the contiguity)

```
perl -pi -e 's/(?:\G(?!\A)|STATE\h)\S*\K\h/_/g'
```

An other way with perl: (whitespaces are replaced only in group 1)

```
perl -pi -e 's/STATE\h\K(.+)/$1=~s#\h#_#gr/e'
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk should work for this:

```
awk 'p=index($0, " STATE ") {s=substr($0, p+7); gsub(/ /, "_", s); $5=s; NF=5} 1' file
12 0.185861000 4294967296 STATE A_variable_name
12 0.187326000 4294967296 STATE Another_variable_name
12 0.187629000 4294967296 STATE Another_variable_name
12 0.187823000 4294967296 STATE A_variable_name
```

`$5=s` is done to assign changed values back to `$0` and `NF=5` is done to remove old values.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU AWK

```
awk -F"STATE " '{gsub(" ","_",$2);print $1"STATE "$2}' <file>
```

Split the input with "STATE " as FS and replace space from $2. You can use "[[:space:]]" if you have tabs and space

You can use

```
awk -F"STATE " '{gsub(" ","_",$2);print}' <file>
```

But this introduces additional one space after STATE

Comment: Nice idea, take care to define the output field separator: `awk -F"STATE " -vOFS="STATE " '{gsub(" ","_",$2)}1'`

Answer (score 1):

With perl, I'd probably tackle it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#read a line
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    #split the first 5 fields into @stuff
    my @stuff = split( ' ', $line, 5 );
    #transform the whitespace in each field to _
    print join( " ", map { s/ /_/g; $_} @stuff );
}

__DATA__
   12 0.185861000 4294967296 STATE A variable name
   12 0.187326000 4294967296 STATE Another variable name
   12 0.187629000 4294967296 STATE Another variable name
   12 0.187823000 4294967296 STATE A variable name
```

Which produces:

```
12 0.185861000 4294967296 STATE A_variable_name
12 0.187326000 4294967296 STATE Another_variable_name
12 0.187629000 4294967296 STATE Another_variable_name
12 0.187823000 4294967296 STATE A_variable_name
```

This will strip leading whitespace. You can retain it if you split with: `split ( / /, $line, 8 )` instead. (you need the `8` because the leading whitespaces each count as a field in their own right).

This could one-liner as:

```
perl -ne 'print join( " ", map {s/ /_/g; $_} split( ' ', $_, 5 ))' yourfilename
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -nE '@a = /(.*?STATE\s+)(.*)$/; $a[1] =~ s/\s+/_/g; say @a' in.txt

12 0.185861000 4294967296 STATE A_variable_name
12 0.187326000 4294967296 STATE Another_variable_name
12 0.187629000 4294967296 STATE Another_variable_name
12 0.187823000 4294967296 STATE A_variable_name
```